# Error calling cordaRPCOps.startFlowDynamic()

Tags: corda

I am building an RPC interface that calls cordaRPCOps.startFlowDynamic() and got the following error:

> Class "class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29" is not on the whitelist or
> annotated with @CordaSerializable.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally included an extra parameter to the cordaRPCOps.startFlowDynamic() call:

```
FlowHandle<SignedTransaction> flowHandle = cordaRPCOps.startFlowDynamic(
    FungibleTokenRedeem.class, 
    amount,
    issuer, 
    observers, 
    queryCriteria, 
    changeHolder, 
    cordaRPCOps     // !!! Extra parameter !!!
);
```

Here is the constructor for the Flow:

```
public FungibleTokenRedeem(Amount<TokenType> amount, Party issuer, List<Party> observers, QueryCriteria queryCriteria, AbstractParty changeHolder) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.issuer = issuer;
    this.observers = observers;
    this.queryCriteria = queryCriteria;
    this.changeHolder = changeHolder;
}
```

Normally when you have too many, too few or the wrong type of parameter to cordaRPCOps.startFlowDynamic() you get a nice error that helps you identify what you did wrong:

> net.corda.core.flows.IllegalFlowLogicException: A FlowLogicRef cannot
> be constructed for FlowLogic of type
> com.template.flows.FungibleToken.FungibleTokenRedeem: due to ambiguous
> match against the constructors

In the past when I accidentally included an extra parameter it just happened to be one that is on Corda’s whitelist (i.e. String, List<> etc.).  This time the class happened to be class CordaRPCOps (copy and paste mistake) which is not on the whitelist or annotated with @CordaSerializable and this more cryptic error message was the result.  I just wanted a record of it in case someone makes the same mistake.